# Django separate DB engine for unit tests

Tags: django, tdd

I am new to Django and following several tutorials. I created a separate app for functional testing. I also setup a postgres DB engine for my prod DBMS but for testing I'd like to use SQLite3 in memory. Could someone tell me how to override the prod DB with another settings.py file? Where would I put the override file, in my functional test app folder? How does Django know which settings to use for prod vs. testing? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an option:
Create a file names settings_test.py that contains something like:

```
from settings import * # if your main settings file is settings.py
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
# and whatever other settings like db name etc.
```

Then run tests with the settings:

```
./manage.py test --settings=settings_test
```

Comment: Not bad, but this forces me out of my IDE to the command line for running tests in Django. I use the PyCharm plugin for Idea and I don't see an option for passing cmd line opts. I would alias the manage command to include the opt but I'm also on Windows. Is there a python variable that gets set only when running test that I could use to conditionalize my db engine? Would this be a good alternative approach?

Comment: There is a possibility in pycharm to run django command. When your press ctrl+enter (cmd+enter for mac) it shows you an input field for command line parameters

Comment: You may find it under help -> Find action. Start typing "manage.py" and follow instructions).
And sorry, i missed the place you said you were on windows, i'm not sure if it would work(

Comment: I just tried cntrl+enter in Windows Idea both before and after selecting test from the "Run manage task" option ant I didn't get the option to enter cmd line options. Thanks I will keep looking into this.

Comment: I'm sorry, my pycharm says it's shift+enter :-), but when you see the list of available command it has to show you which shortcut to use

Comment: I just tried running from the cmd line and I must be really green b/c I can't get it to work. I get ImportError: Could not import settings 'mypythonapp\settings_test.py' (Is it on sys
.path?): Import by filename is not supported. I have manage.py in the parent directory to mypythonapp which is where the original settings.py is located. Should I run the tests from mypythonapp folder?

Comment: try  
`--settings=mypythonapp.settings_test`  
if the structure looks like this:  
/manage.py  
/mypythonapp/  
/mypythonapp/__init.py__  
/mypythonapp/settings_test.py

Comment: I give up, i tried to put new lines to the structure, so it looked nicer, but i can't(

Comment: Hey thanks Dima! I'll try a little later after my real job and possibly ping back later tonight.

Comment: FInally got around to trying this. I found shift+enter in IntelliJ, but it doesn't seem to be passing the "--settings=settings_test" correctly. I put a print in my settings_test.py to see if it was being run and I never see the print. I'm going to try running from cmd line next.

Comment: Works from the cmd line! I need to figure out why parameters are not being passed correctly in PyCharm, but thanx a heap!

Comment: Figured it out! I had to create a test configuration and set my custom settings file there. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Dima's answer, you can take a look at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#using-another-settings-module